# No me aparece el atributo prototype

Tags: javascript

estaba estudiando la herencia prototipada en javascript, sucede lo siguiente
queria mutar el prototipo de mi objeto haciendo uso de prototype en vez de **proto** pero no me funciona, alguien sabe porque?

Mi codigo es el siguiente:

```js
let persona21 = {nombre: "Jefferson Go"}

let empleado21 = {salario:23.45}

empleado21.prototype = persona21
```

Pero no me funciona a como se espera lo que ocurre es que se crea un atributo que se llama asi y no el objeto en si tiene un prototype, y la unica forma en la que me sirve el proceso de mutación de prototipos es accediendo a **proto** pero dicen que no es optimo y se deberia usar prototype pero prototype me sale como si no existiese al momento de querer acceder a este...

Comment: tienes que asignarle un objeto `persona21` al `empleado21` de esta forma  `empleado21.prototype.persona21 = persona21;` o lo que es lo mismo `empleado21.prototype.persona21 = {salario:23.45}`

Comment: @Bryro ponlo como respuesta, que tiene pinta de serlo

Answer (score 0):

Los prototipos se definen como funciones en Javascript:

```
let proto = function() {
   this.prop1 = "hola"
   this.prop2 = 2.3
}

proto.prototype.prop3 = new Array();
```

en el caso que tu buscas, sería algo parecido a esto:

```js
let persona21 = {nombre: "Jefferson Go"}

let salario21 = {salario: 23.45}

let empleado21 = function(){}

empleado21.prototype.nombre = persona21.nombre
empleado21.prototype.salario = salario21.salario
```